# How can you clean an entire POSIX tree with only POSIX functions?

Tags: c, posix

Having populated a POSIX binary tree with `tsearch`, how is it possible to clean-up the entire tree? GCC provides `tdestroy` as an extension, but if you want to use POSIX-only functions how can you do it?

My current implementation uses `twalk` to walk the tree and, for `endorder` and `leaf` nodes, calls `tdelete`, but this understandably shows warnings about const-correctness:

```c
static void free_tree(const void *node, const VISIT which, const int depth)
{
        struct search_entry *entry;
        switch (which) {
                case endorder:
                case leaf:
                        entry = *(struct search_entry **)node;
                        tdelete(entry->key, &node, search_entry_compare);
                        free(entry);
        }
}
```

What was the expected approach for POSIX-compliant applications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The POSIX description of the [`tsearch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tsearch.html) family of functions has an informative *Examples* section which shows how the standard thinks you can delete all the elements of a tree (as part of a bigger, complete example of how to use the functions):

> ```
> /* Delete all nodes in the tree */
> while (root != NULL) {
>     elementptr = *(struct element **)root;
>     printf("deleting node: string = %s,  count = %d\n",
>            elementptr->string,
>            elementptr->count);
>     tdelete((void *)elementptr, &root, delete_root);
>     free(elementptr);
> }
> ```

Basically, it repeatedly deletes the root node with `tdelete()` until there is no longer a root node to delete.  The `delete_root()` function is also shown — it is a no-op that returns 0 for success.

We can debate the merits (or lack of them) for the cast in the call to `tdelete()`.

Comment: Too bad the Linux programmers manual doesn't contain something like this; all it has as of 4.16 is how to expose and use `tdestroy`.

Comment: Yeah, the `3posix` man page for `tdestroy` omits this, would be very useful.
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution of calling `tdelete()` from `twalk()`'s `action` conflicts with the POSIX requirement on the application that `action` and `compar` not change the tree. In practice, a use after free or incomplete cleanup is likely.

The best I can think of is either not using tsearch/tfind/tdelete/twalk or allocating new memory to store `twalk()` results and using `tdelete()` afterwards.

Not using tsearch/tfind/tdelete/twalk may also allow data structures such as radix tries and hash tables that tend to be more efficient on modern architectures than binary trees.

Comment: I would not avoid tsearch because "radix tries and hash tables [...] tend to be more efficient on modern architectures" unless you actually have a performance problem you're trying to solve and you've measured that it makes a difference. The tsearch API is really easy to use, optimal big-O, not dependent on type of keys (whereas radix is), and tends to make code very light and simple.